# why does this for loop always only adds 1's to the array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I made a two dimensional String array in java, and in the last row, which has the index of 6, I want put in numbers from 1 to 7 on every second space of the array. My code looks like this:

```
    for(int i = 1; i < columns; i += 2) {
        int number = 1;
        fieldArray[6][i] = Integer.toString(number);
        number++;
    }
```

My problem is that the output of the last row of the 2 dimensional array looks like this:

```
null 1 null 1 null 1 null 1 null 1 null 1 null 1 null
```

I don't understand why, the way I understood for loops is that in the first iteration it starts with an index of 1, adds the content of the variable number which is converted to a String to fit in the String array, then the variable number is increased by one, next iteration, index is 3, and number is 2, but the content of index 3 is one as well, why?

The nulls in the array are there on purpose, I want to add something different using the same kind of for loop but with a different offset later.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) --- "*why does this for loop always only adds 1's to the array*" - Because you set it to `1` right before parsing. Try using `Integer.toString(i)` instead of `Integer.toString(number)`.

Comment: But I want to put in the value of the number variable, the iterator i is just for the index of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are defining the `number` variable each time, for each iteration setting it to 1.
You should define `number` outside the `for` loop, before it.
Something like this:

```
int number = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < columns; i += 2) {
    fieldArray[6][i] = Integer.toString(number);
    number++;
}
```

Comment: This is the most basic error and I am embarassed haha, thank you so much

Comment: It's okay. In case this resolved your problem please accept the answer to indicate the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to put in the value of the number variable, the iterator i is just for the index of the array? –

Some details are lacking in your ultimate requirement.  One thing though it is is best to use variables instead of unassigned constants.

```
int number = 1;
int rows = 7;
int columns = 15;
String[][] fieldArray = new String[rows][columns];
for (int i = 1; i < columns; i += 2) {
    fieldArray[6][i] = Integer.toString(number);
    number++;
}

for (String[] s : fieldArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    
}
```

Prints

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, 1, null, 2, null, 3, null, 4, null, 5, null, 6, null, 7, null]
```

Comment: I actually do that, this is just a bit of my code, looks good tho and the method to print out the array looks better than what I do right now, thank you

Comment: OK.   I wasn't certain so I thought I would seek some clarification.